# Some of the API in ASP.Net Core 3.1 CORS is not working

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using ASP.net core 3.1 web api and angular 9. Some of the API request throwing Cross origin error and some time it is working fine.`public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddControllers();

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
            });
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Title = "API",
                Version = "v1"
            });
        });

        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.RegisterService();
        services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    }` ` public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (Env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }`
```

Comment: Hi Vignesh. Please share some code and show your effort.

Comment: Some codes added here

Comment: Can you show your error message and show the code causing the error？

Comment: has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.